# ProducerConsumer modified

Tags: java, multithreading, conditional-statements

I had a normal working Producer/Consumer pattern.
It had 1 Producer and N consumer.

Now I## Heading ## wanted to try to produce and then consume at the same time but still using 1 Producer and N consumer threads.;

So basically it should go like produce()->consume(), produce()->consume(), produce()->consume()...

but now that I have multiple consumer Threads I want them to await() at the condition, so if after produce()->consume() another consume() happens place it waits.

So say I have 1 Producer and 4 Consumer it could look like this:

produce()->consume()->consume().await->consume().await()->consume().await()->produce()->...

**Question**: The code works but what I don't understand, after the producer-Thread goes into cond.await(); how comes he can still call cond1.signalAll();?
Shouldn't the sequential code stop right at cond.await()?

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Processor {
    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private Condition cond = lock.newCondition();
    private Condition cond1 = lock.newCondition();
    private int Counter = 0;

    public void produce() throws InterruptedException {
        while(true) {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                Counter++;
                System.out.println("Increased by one");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                cond.await();
                cond1.signalAll();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }   
        }
    }

    public void consume() throws InterruptedException{
        while(true) {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                while(Counter==0) {
                    cond1.await();
                }
                Counter--;
                System.out.println("Decreased by one!");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                cond.signalAll();           
            }
            finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your producer/consumer setup can fail and I will discuss how that is the cause but will initially explain why it works somewhat.  The reason that the producer does call the cond1.signalAll is how you've setup the producer consumer communication.  The Counter field is the reason that the producer gets to call the cond1.signalAll method.  There are scenarios that are possible in this case.

Let us start to assume that the producer gains the lock before any of the consumers do.  The producer will then increment the Counter and will place itself in a wait condition using the cond.await call.  This will cause the producer to relinquish its lock and allow for one of the consumers to gain the lock.  The consumer that gains the lock will then see that the count is greater than zero and proceed to decrement the counter.  It will then call the cond.signalAll and cause the producer to reclaim the lock.  The consumer then release the lock and tries to regain the lock.  If the producer regains the lock it will perform the same process that was mentioned above.  If instead a consumer gains the lock and it will notice that the counter is zero and place itself in a wait condition by calling cond1.await.  In this case, the producer will eventually gain the lock.

The other scenario is if the consumer gains the lock prior to the producer gaining the lock.  The consumer will see that the counter is zero and it will place itself in a wait state using cond1.await. It will then relinquish its lock and another thread will get the lock.  The producer can then gain the lock and be able to increment the counter and place itself in a wait state.  The consumer will then gain the lock and be able to consume the counter before signaling the producer.

What happens if all of the consumers will gain the lock prior to the producer gaining the lock?  In that case the consumer will perform the same steps as mentioned above.  Eventually the producer will gain the lock and will increment the counter.  Note that in that case the producer will wait prior to signally the consumer to wake up.  This will cause your producer/consumer to wait forever without doing any work.  This is the only case that will cause your system to fail.  It is then recommend that you first signal that you've have work for the consumers prior to placing the producer is a wait state.  Note that this case can only happen when you initially start the producer/consumer threads.  You can easily reproduce this case by starting all of the consumer threads and wait for some length of time and then start the producer.  This will generate the aforementioned case.  This is really a boundary case that you just need to take into account.